# Spring Security Remember-me checkbox

Tags: spring-security, remember-me

There is a login form in the application. By default, I can't log in if I don't check on the remember-me checkbox.

There are two methods to configure remember-me:

```
.tokenValiditySeconds(int...)
.alwaysRemember(boolean...)
```

To be able to login with the unchecked box I should set remember-me flag programmatically with `alwaysRemember(true)`.

But then what's the reason to have remember-me checkbox if I have to set the flag programmatically?

`tokenValiditySeconds()` sets the max, not the min number of seconds. Is there a way to set the min number of seconds so the user could log in with the unchecked box?

Comment: why you are setting it manually just set it as .rememberMe() and try, by using alwaysRemember you are telling spring to take always to remember me setting as yes or no despite the setting in the login page.

Comment: yes, I set it as .rememberMe() .alwaysRemember(true), otherwise (without .alwaysRemember(true)) a user can't login without manual setting. Why then does this checkbox exist? Nobody wants to enter the correct name/password and fail (because of the unchecked box).

Comment: @Ekaterina: Show your full Spring Security configuration class, not only two lines.